# Is there any way to distinguish between a community page and the lightning page in core development?

Tags: customer-community, lightning-community

Currently, we have one use case where we have an existing functionality to open a tab when clicking on a button, but as communities don't support tabs, we had to devise an approach to open a modal with the same content as the tab. So to that we need some conditional rendering check to open the modal at the click of a button in the case of the community page only.

So can we know through URL or something else, whether the page is lightning or a community page?

Comment: Have you considered using [Network ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_network.htm#apex_System_Network_getNetworkId)?